# tensorflow-gpu installation problem on system with multiple cuda versions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow-gpu using

`sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu` on python3.6

The system I am using has both cuda 10 and cuda 9.0 installed on it.

I have exported the cuda 9.0 paths, but `import tensorflow` still gives me

`ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Is there any way I can force tensorflow to use cuda 9.0 because the default pre-compiled tensorflow using pip only works with cuda 9.0 according to the official documentation.

Additional info:

1. I do not want to use a virtualenv because I am installing tensorflow for the entire system so that all users can use it.
2. I have in the past installed tensorflow after compiling with bazel, but only I was able to use it. Other users could not, even after exporting the cuda paths to their profiles. So, I am trying to make the default pip installation work this time. I have uninstalled the previous tensorflow installation successfully.

Comment: try installing a different version of tensorflow like 1.11.0 i.e a version that supports cuda 9

Comment: this worked. i installed 1.12.0 instead, though. thanks!

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain can you please post your comment as an answer so that i can accept?

Comment: done happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing a different version of tensorflow like 1.11.0 i.e a version that supports cuda 9

Answer (score -2):

To import tensorflow your environment should have numpy.So check numpy is installed or not using import numpy? If it is intalled then install tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu using following commands.

```
activate yourEnvName
conda install tensorflow
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```